# Replacement for deprecated SAP UI5 Control "TextView"

Tags: sapui5

What is the recommended replacement for the SAP UI5 Control "TextView", which is deprecated since 1.38?

I found this outdated Control while working through the SAPUI5 [Walkthrough tutorial](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db) and following a ["related information" link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/04575456e15e426d81054805990c7a53.html) that is still using on the old TextView Control.

There is no replacement info given in the API Reference of TextView:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.commons.TextView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sap.m.Text](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.m.Text) instead. [Api](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.m.Text).

View example:

```
<mvc:View
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
        <Text text="Lorem ipsum dolor st amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat" />
    </VBox>
</mvc:View>
```